# How to group an array of objects individually into single ones

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm using lodash to group an array of objects:

```
let people = [
  {name:'carl',group:'one'}, 
  {name:'john',group:'one'}, 
  {name:'dean',group:'three'}
]

_.groupBy(people,"group");
```

**Result:**

```
one: Array (2 items)
0: Object {group: "one", name: "carl"}
1: Object {group: "one", name: "john"}

three: Array (1 item)
0: Object {group: "three", name: "dean"}
```

What I want is the objects with group array length higher than 1 to separate into another array individually like this:

```
one: Array (1 item)
0: Object {group: "one", name: "carl"}

one: Array (1 item)
0: Object {group: "one", name: "john"}

three: Array (1 item)
0: Object {group: "three", name: "dean"}
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: You can not have an object of the second format, since you have clashing key names (`one` in this case)

Comment: The most you can do is: `{"key": {'one': []}, "otherkey": {'one': []}, ....}`

Comment: But, if you're using a structure with that kind of complexity, why not just use the structure returned from _.groupBy? it's pretty clean, and you should be able to adjust your implementation to fit it

Comment: Im not sure I understand what is being asked here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the method "sort"

```
let people = [{name:'carl',group:'one'}, 
 {name:'john',group:'one'}, 
 {name:'dean',group:'three'}];

people.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
});
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort